# showAlert delete my ID

Tags: javascript, dialog, alert

first i'm sorry about my English :)

i have a Problem with my Code, he delete my ID. I think he make my table cell to a Dialog. Here is my code.

```
function showAlert(){

$( "#dropzoneorg" ).dialog({modal: true});


<td id="dropzoneorg"></td>
```

I want to show via Alert what is inside in dropzoneorg.
Now its working but he delete my

Here is a Picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td id="dropzoneorg"></td> 

<script>
function showAlert(){

//retrieving value
var dropzone = $('#dropzoneorg').html();

//setting the value for the pop up
$('#diaplog span').html(dropzone);

//Pop up trigger
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal: true});

}

</script>



<div id="dialog">
<span> <span>
</div>
```

This may help you.

Comment: If my code is working for you means, kindly click the "correct answer mark" on left ride .

Comment: Hey Hey thanks for fast answer but its not working... nothing happened

Comment: show me or send me the screen of your code after my guidance.

Comment: On  this $( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal: true}); line you should give the dialog division id on selector. 

ex: $('dialog_div_id_here').dialog({modal: true});

Comment: How can i send you a massage?

Comment: If i make this one : $( "#dropzoneorg" ).dialog({modal: true}); it show me the input in a pop up dialog but behind he delete my <td>

Comment: The Problem i must to use this one without a div:  <tr><td>Org.</td></div>
                    <td id="dropzoneorg"><br></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<input readonly type="text" value="6" id="id_seiten_org" name="seiten_org" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" value="ja" id="id_farbe_org" name="farbe_org ">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" value="ja" id="id_doppel_org" name="doppel_org" >&nbsp;</td>
                 
                </tr>

Comment: Okay then use my code without editing or any corrections. Just use mine fully.

`<td id="dropzoneorg"></td> 

<script>
function showAlert(){

//retrieving value
var dropzone = $('#dropzoneorg').html();

//setting the value for the pop up
$('#diaplog span').html(dropzone);

//Pop up trigger
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal: true});

}

</script>



<div id="dialog">
<span> <span>
</div>`

Comment: hmm i just used youre code but again without input just a popup empty

Comment: am sorry use this 

`<td id="dropzoneorg"></td> 

<script>
function showAlert(){

//retrieving value
var dropzone = $('#dropzoneorg').html();

//setting the value for the pop up
$('#dialog span').html(dropzone);

//Pop up trigger
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal: true});

}

</script>



<div id="dialog">
<span> <span>
</div>`

Comment: Thankyou. please click the Correct mark on left side.

Comment: cant find that where?

Comment: near my first answer. Left side (Right Mark).

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. :)

Comment: no no thank you very much 3 Day working on it ufff:)